# Crear un servidor web publico en una PC

Tags: php, python, http, go

Tengo algunas preguntas ya que quiero hacer una web, pero no decido si hacerlo en casa o en un Hosting y quiero saber lo bueno y lo malo de hacer una web en "casa"

1. La web se publicará 24 horas
2. El tráfico hará que Internet sea más lento para mi y todos
3. Y para terminar el www.domain.com será propio

   [image]

Comment: Hola Shareiv, creo que olvidaste la pregunta. Por favor, lee detenidamente esta guía [__¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?__](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Procura que tus preguntas no soliciten opiniones, ideas o sugerencias. De preferencia, recuerda incluir un __[mcve]__.

Comment: en Linode y Digital Ocean consigues un VPS por 5$ al mes. Es lo más barato que vas a encontrar con total acceso root :D

Comment: @fredyfx ok un VPN que mas?

Comment: VPN (Virtual Private Network) != VPS (Virtual Private Server). Ahí levantas las tecnologías que necesites.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque es off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta decisión dependerá de muchos factores, entre ellos el dinero del que dispongas para pagar un hosting, la capacidad de procesamiento y recursos de hardware que dispones en tu hogar, y por sobre todo la importancia de tu proyecto para estar en linea 24 horas.
Tenerlo en tu casa tiene como ventajas (ademas del ahorro del costo del hosting) la facilidad de instalar todo el soft de base que necesites asi como la instalacion  y administracion de tu propio web server, application server dedicado y base de datos. Evitaras con esto tener que buscar un hosting que se adapte a tus requerimientos de software y de proyecto.
Sera mas sencillo tambien buscar futuros errores de aplicacion ya que podrias realizar debug directamente en tu propio servidor.....
Las desventajas de tenerlo es tu casa son varias...entre ellas, algo tan sencillo como un corte de energía o de internet de tu ISP hará que tu sitio pueda estar caido por horas, hasta dias...Por otro lado, tenerlo en casa no da seguridad en terminos de escalabilidad, es decir si tu sitio crece rapidamente, probablemente no tendrás los recursos de hardware para soportar un crecimiento importante de usuarios. Otra desventaja son las herramientas de seguridad y backup que deberas implementar tu mismo, cosa que en un buen hosting ya estan resueltas.